# how to make a picturebox image change depending on what is selected in a combobox

Tags: picturebox

Im using C# but all I find are how to do it in Visual Basic.
I've already added the images to a folder. ![enter image description here][1]
I just don't know how to make the if else statement to change the picture depending on the selection in the combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load all the images to Image objects, like so

```
Image picture1 = Image.FromFile(filepath)
```

From there, you've got two options.

1) Use a timer. In the timer, make it check the value of the combo box and switch out the PIctureBox.Image by using

```
PictureBox.Image = picturel // or whatever you named your image
```

2) In the ComboBox Change event, use the above code depending on the value of the combo box when the event is triggered.

Either way will produce the desired result. :)